# Android Studio:Uncaught translation error, ExceptionWithContext

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to migrate my app from eclipse to Android Studio. I did not use import feature, creating project based on very simple one. I managed to successfully build project but I got next error when I try to run my app.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Uncaught translation error: com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}
```

I see similar errors with Google search but I could not find a fix for this issue.

My build.gradle looks like this. (I removed signingConfigs.)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.dailytimer.imadoco"
        minSdkVersion 9
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFile 'C:/Android/AndroidStudioProjects/imadoco/document/proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            versionCode 30800
            versionName '3.08.0'
            applicationId 'net.DailyTimer.imadocoFree'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/acra-4.6.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
}
```

I tried with --stacktrace and --debug option to get more logs, but not helped.

```
19:32:19.775 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:dexFreeDebug'
19:32:19.775 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:dexFreeDebug FAILED
19:32:19.776 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:dexFreeDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 32,5,main]) completed. Took 6.205 secs.
19:32:19.776 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 32,5,main]] finished, busy: 10.137 secs, idle: 0.032 secs

19:32:19.777 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
19:32:19.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
19:32:19.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
19:32:19.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
19:32:19.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:dexFreeDebug'.
19:32:19.778 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
19:32:19.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
19:32:19.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
19:32:19.779 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:dexFreeDebug'.
19:32:19.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
19:32:19.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
19:32:19.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
19:32:19.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
19:32:19.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
19:32:19.780 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
19:32:19.781 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
19:32:19.782 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
19:32:19.788 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
19:32:19.795 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
19:32:19.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
19:32:19.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
19:32:19.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
19:32:19.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
19:32:19.796 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
19:32:19.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
19:32:19.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
19:32:19.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
19:32:19.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
19:32:19.797 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
19:32:19.798 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
19:32:19.798 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
19:32:19.798 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
19:32:19.798 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
19:32:19.799 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
19:32:19.799 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
19:32:19.799 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
19:32:19.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
19:32:19.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
19:32:19.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
19:32:19.800 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
19:32:19.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
19:32:19.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
19:32:19.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
19:32:19.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
19:32:19.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
19:32:19.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
19:32:19.801 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
19:32:19.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
19:32:19.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
19:32:19.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
19:32:19.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
19:32:19.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
19:32:19.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
19:32:19.802 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
19:32:19.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
19:32:19.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
19:32:19.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
19:32:19.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
19:32:19.803 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
19:32:19.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:45)
19:32:19.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:78)
19:32:19.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
19:32:19.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
19:32:19.804 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
19:32:19.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
19:32:19.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
19:32:19.805 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
19:32:19.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 57 more
19:32:19.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
19:32:19.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:42)
19:32:19.806 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.convertByteCode(AndroidBuilder.java:1276)
19:32:19.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$convertByteCode$7.call(Unknown Source)
19:32:19.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.doTaskAction(Dex.groovy:165)
19:32:19.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.this$6$doTaskAction(Dex.groovy)
19:32:19.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex$this$6$doTaskAction.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
19:32:19.807 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Dex.taskAction(Dex.groovy:99)
19:32:19.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
19:32:19.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 63 more
19:32:19.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
19:32:19.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
19:32:19.808 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:40)
19:32:19.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 70 more
19:32:19.809 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

Any help is welcome.

[Edit 1]

I checked log output and it seems problem is related to support-annotations... which I don't know about. But experts may find it useful.

```
processing archive C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\imadoco\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\free\debug\support-annotations-23.1.0-24c46cbde714be0842274322039416f341dd73a0.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource android/
ignored resource android/support/
ignored resource android/support/annotation/
processing classes.dex...
23:07:52.739 [ERROR] [org.gradle.api.Project] AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"Uncaught translation error: com.android.dex.util.ExceptionWithContext","sources":[{}]}
1 error; aborting
23:07:52.739 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:dexFreeDebug'
23:07:52.739 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:dexFreeDebug FAILED
23:07:52.740 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:dexFreeDebug (Thread[Daemon worker Thread 5,5,main]) completed. Took 3.06 secs.
23:07:52.740 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[Daemon worker Thread 5,5,main]] finished, busy: 6.815 secs, idle: 0.025 secs
23:07:52.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:07:52.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
23:07:52.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:07:52.741 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
23:07:52.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:dexFreeDebug'.
23:07:52.742 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

[Edit 2]

I added support-annotations library as it seems to be linked too after googling about "support-annotions" but it did not help. Exact same error persisted.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/acra-4.6.1.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
}
```

[Edit 3]

Since java.exe is returning error to Gradle, java.exe should know the place/file which found error. But there is no log from java.exe itself. I checked Gradle documentation but could not find a way to let get logs (standard output?) of java.exe. How can I do this? I guess that error message may lead me to the right place to look at.

[Edit 4]

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498183/exceptionwithcontext-gets-thrown-when-trying-to-build-an-android-app-with-ant) and I checked code style shown below.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
{
    myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do something
        }
    });
}
```

I had many lines of code that will be deleted by optimization, using static final variable (like BuildConfig.DEBUG) to control code behavior depending on build mode like debug/release, free/paid. But I could not find same pattern that the thread pointed as an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I could find a solution. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189912/576442) saved my life.

In my case, I have code below which is a cause of this annoying issue.

```
private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback
{
    public void allow()
    {
```

And making this class **public** fixed this.

```
public class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback
{
    public void allow()
    {
```

Just one word, "private" in one file caused that issue and since build system didn't give any hint where we should look at, it was very hard to fix. I googled a lot and I saw [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21189912/576442) only in one thread in SO. Without that answer, I could not fix this issue. Thanks Johny_G and this community.

For those who suffer from same issue, first commit current code to any VCS then try search and replace word "private" to "public" in one bulk operation (using good editor) and build/run. If issue goes away, put few files back to previous one and build/run to see what file has key "private".

Comment: Cheers ! .Happy coding

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, I wish you can do something to change this. Facing to this issue is absolute unhappy.

Comment: That was exactly my problem ! Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: Same for me when genarate signed APK. You save my night

Comment: Both class and method are public, but problem is still exist!

Answer (score 3):

I've hand this issue crop up twice recently. Last time I found something somewhere on here that mentioned anonymous classes getting optimised out (this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22010135/2214006). For me, this error was fixed by adjusting such a block of code.

eg.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    // etc
  });
}
```

Would cause this error when building a release version. Attempting to make it work by assigning it to a variable first didn't help as it was still optimised out:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  FindCallback<ParseObject> findHandler = new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    // etc
  };
  query.findInBackground(findHandler);
}
```

I didn't want it created when BuildConfig.DEBUG was false, so I put it in a separate class:

```
private class FindHandler implements FindCallback<ParseObject> {
  //etc
}
```

Then in the main part of my code:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
  query.findInBackground(new FindHandler());
}
```

Comment: I saw your answer right after I added [Edit 4] to my question, which refers to same thread. As I wrote in [Edit 4], I could not find code fits into this pattern. Since it looks like good place to check, I will investigate my code more. And thank you for helping me.

Comment: I guess the first this is does it compile in debug mode but not release (or the other way around)?

In my app, I have a variety of flags that compile in various different bits of debugging so I could flick those off one by one to narrow down which area of the program the issue was in. Sorry I can't help more, I know how frustrating it can be trying to chase down these kind of weird, build tool related issues.

Comment: I could find a solution  which was different from yours but since you were only one who did answer, you are eligible to bounty.

Comment: Stoked that you found your answer! I wonder if this is with raising as a bug in the build tools? It'd be nice if it at least gave you the filename where the "error" occurs...

Answer (score 0):

Also happens when you add `annotation processors` as `compile` dependencies. They should be `provided`.

For example, I had:

```
compiled 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'
```

which should be:

```
provided 'frankiesardo:icepick-processor:3.2.0'
```